# detect Bluetooth Discovery is on?

Tags: android

I want to detect whether Bluetooth discovery is on or no ? 
is it possible ?

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 1);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

above code is about enabling /diabling blutooth disc state  , but do not show bluetooth disco state

Comment: when you say "whether Bluetooth discovery is on or no?", do you mean whether your device is discoverable, or whether it's in the process of discovery, i.e. discovering other devices?

Answer (score 4):

To find out if the bluetooth device is discoverable (in the inquiry scan state), use `getScanMode()`, as in the following:

```
BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(bAdapter.getScanMode() == BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
    // device is discoverable & connectable
} else {
    // device is not discoverable & connectable
}
```

[Documentation of getScanMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getScanMode%28%29) :

> **int android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getScanMode()**
>
> Get the current Bluetooth scan mode of the local Bluetooth adapter.
>
> The Bluetooth scan mode determines if the local adapter is connectable
>   and/or discoverable from remote Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering();
```

should do what you're looking for. You can get the default BluetoothAdapter object via:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

You can read about both of those methods in the [Android BluetoothAdapter doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html).

Comment: Without seeing the error message, I can't be sure, but my guess is that you need to make sure that bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() is true - also covered in that doc. Could you post the error?